# Как правильно создать ajax запрос?

Tags: php, ajax

Все происходит на wordpress,

Сам запрос:

```
$(function(){


 var ajaxurl = '<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>';

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: ajaxurl,
                data:{
                action: 'weather_block'
                },
                dataType: 'html',
                success: function(response){
                $('.weather_block_page').html(response);
                console.log(response);
    },
    error : function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        $loader.html(jqXHR + " :: " + textStatus + " :: " + errorThrown);
    }

});
        });
```

И есть файл куда приходит запрос:

```
function weather_block_ajax_request(){
   echo 'test';
   die();
  }
    add_action('wp_ajax_weather_block', 'weather_block_ajax_request');
    add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_weather_block', 'weather_block_ajax_request');
```

В консоле я получаю 0, почему?

Comment: убедитесь, что запрос приходит на этот файл (в начале файла воткнуть `exit('abc')` - если в консоли `abc`, значит все верно). Если здесь все хорошо - разбирайтесь с `add_action`. Значит не вешается ваша функция на эти хуки или эти хуки не срабатывают. Где вы нашли такие хуки? есть ссылка?

Comment: abc вижу в source! хуки взял с оф. страницы wordpress. Пробовал менять название функции и action, результат тот же, 0

Comment: уточните, что такое 0 и где вы его видите. можно скриншот для ясности.

Comment: тут особо думать нечего, на самом деле: если вы ставите `exit('abc')` рядом с приведенным вами кодом в php и у вас в консоль выводится `abc` - у вас все в порядке с запросом. Не работают хуки. Пробуйте другие.

Comment: https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins

Ну в консоле я вижу 0 )) где же еще.

Comment: консоль, знаете ли, понятие растяжимое. разные люди понимают под консолью вообще разные вещи. один думает что консоль - это панелька, которая на f12 открывается, другой может 0 вообще не связанный с запросом увидеть и сказать "у меня 0 в консоли!". мне нужен точный ответ - 0 это ответ от сервера или нет? посмотрите на вкладке network запрос и убедитесь, что его ответ действительно 0.

Comment: Консоль, это вкладка console, в которой я вижу 0 (console.log(response);), на вкладке network, я вижу запрос с (action:weather_block)

Comment: Сдается мне, что die() просто прибивает выполнение скриптов и вордпрес не отрабатывает вывод html. В ответе вы видите только 0 или что-то, что введено в die

Comment: я пробовал по разному, менял название функции, менял название action, пробовал по другому запрос делать, писал в die(), все равно 0